# nodejs forever: start application

Tags: node.js, forever

I am running my web app with `npm start` but now I need to deploy it to Digital Ocean which means that I'll have to use `forever` to start my app and I can't figure this out...

I tried to run it as `forever npm start` but it returns:

> error:   Cannot start forever
>   error:   script /root/saleseng/OP Apps Platform/server/npm does not exist.

This is my `scrips` object from `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --watch src --exec babel-node -- src/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }
```

Comment: Try this "forever start -c "npm start" /path/to/app/dir/"

Comment: Found here: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/540#issuecomment-37762716

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass the name of `.js` file to forever:

```
forever start src/index.js
```

This will start the script with forever. It could be monitored with

```
forever logs scriptId -f
```

`forever list` will fetch you the `scriptId`

**UPDATE:**

Transpiling to `ES5`:

To use `babel` have the following dependencies installed:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
}
```

Then create a `.babelrc` in the root of your project having the following:

```
    {
       "presets": ["es2015","stage-0"]
    }
```

Now to finally do a transpile, run:

```
babel myInputDirectory --out-dir myOutputDirectory
```

Comment: It shows this:
`data:    [1] r2hU /usr/bin/nodejs src/index.js   /root/.forever/r2hU.log STOPPED `

Comment: This means your script encountered some error. What happens when you run `node yourfile.js`?

Comment: @Valip What happens when you run `node yourfile.js`?

Comment: Running `node myfile.js` returns `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
`

Comment: @Valip You could either transpile to `es5` and then run from forever or upgrade your `nodejs` version

Comment: Can you tell me how can I transpile to `es5`?

Comment: I see that you already using `babel` as a transpiler. What you could do is first run `babel-node -- src/index.js` to transpile to the configured directory and then start the process using forever `forever start path/to/transpiledCode.js`

Comment: Thank you, but I ran into new issues.. now I get `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`. Isn't there other way to run that file in background without having to transpile to `es5`?

Comment: You would require `require("babel-polyfill");` at the top of transpiled file